# kdb: get column names of non-keyed table

Tags: kdb

Given a non-keyed table like `` t:([]c1:`a`b;c2:10 20) ``, is `cols t` always equivalent to `key flip t`?

(Asking as I saw several `key flip t`'s in a repo I'm working on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, see the bold part of `cols` below

`k){$[.Q.qp x:.Q.v x;.Q.pf,!+x;98h=@x;!+x;11h=@!x;!x;!+0!x]}`